# How to remove these warning when erasing a c string

Tags: c, warnings

How can I remove these warnings?

```
   char foo[10], msg2[100]; 
   int k;
   for (k = 0; foo[k] != NULL; k++) //comparison between pointer and integer
       msg2[k] = NULL; //assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast
```

Thanks.

Comment: What is the type of foo and msg2?

Comment: How are foo and msg2 declared?

Comment: how about showing the declarations for foo and msg2?
(wow - number 3 in 30 seconds :) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   int k;
   for (k = 0; foo[k] != '\0'; k++)
       msg2[k] = '\0';
```

Assign an integer to an integer variable, instead of a pointer.  NULL is a pointer.  It is usually defined as:

```
((void *) 0)
```

Comment: `msg2[k] = '\0';` is generally preferred over `msg2[k] = 0;`, although  both are correct of course.

Comment: @Paul fair enough, though it wasn't included in the question when I wrote the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The warning is right, your usage of NULL is wrong.

NULL was meant for pointers, not for string nul-terminator.

Use zero instead of NULL in your code, in BOTH places.
If you want a special zero, you may use '\0', but that;s redundant.

Answer (score 1):

```
*foo = 0;
```

To "Erase" a C style string, all you need to do is set the first byte to 0.

Comment: And if you want to fill ablock of memory with 0s, use memset

Comment: I believe using `'\0'` instead of `0` makes it more obvious that we're dealing with a char value.